# Parsing lines in text in BASH script

Tags: bash, parsing

Hello and sorry in advance, as I am fairly new to unix/linux/scripting.

I have a txt file that contains 20 or so lines with username:hashedpassword:numericalfield:numericalfield:::, akin to the following:

```
#paswd.txt
jgarcia:9bca3efc64b290e9ad3fa3e0add3c983:22288:0:99999:7:::
tanastsio:924e509403341760676d4f1368c87f8d:28593:0:99999:7:::
dbyrne:328fe8a2642fa5bfd1bfdfd894367e79:0:99999:7:::
```

I need to be able to output specific sections of one or several lines (for instance, just username, just the hashed password, etc.) so that I can pipe the output for other uses (comparisons, variables, other commands.)

What I need to be able to do:

```
input:  $ [necessary command -params] ./paswd.txt
output: $ jgarcia

input:  $ [necessary command -params] ./pswd.txt
output: $ 9bca3efc64b290e9ad3fa3e0add3c983

input:  $ [necessary command -params] ./pswd.txt
output: $ jgarcia
          tanastsio
          dbyrne
```

Bonus if possible:

```
input:  $ [necessary command + params] ./paswd.txt
output: $ dbyrne 328fe8a2642fa5bfd1bfdfd894367e79 (no colons)
```

To clarify some uses:

- command output will ultimately be used to determine whether the hashed password is exactly that of the username.
- command output will ultimately be used to determine if any user's password is "password", etc.

Also, can someone tell me what would've been the proper way to phrase this question? Parsing?  Or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Using `awk` what your are trying to achieve is really easy. Check `man awk` or online docs.

Comment: ^^ http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Comment: Thanks for mentioning your requirements, also put what you've done so far.

Comment: `grep` to filter the file, `cut -d: -f1` to extract the usernames, `-f2` for hashes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For your desired output these command will work:

Print first field after split on `:`, from first line:

```
awk -F ":" '{if (NR==1) { print $1 } }' paswd.txt
```

> jgarcia

Print second field after split on `:`, from first line:

```
awk -F ":" '{if (NR==1) { print $2 } }' paswd.txt
```

> 9bca3efc64b290e9ad3fa3e0add3c983

Print first field after split on `:` on all lines:

```
awk -F ":" '{ print $1 }' paswd.txt
```

> jgarcia
>
> tanastsio
>
> dbyrne

Print first and second field after split on `:` on first line:

```
awk -F ":" '{if (NR==1) { print $1" "$2 } }' paswd.txt
```

> jgarcia 9bca3efc64b290e9ad3fa3e0add3c983

Hope this helps